# Microcopy Fluorescence filter set usefulness

Tags: fluorescence

I have a brief doubt and maybe someone around here can give as some help. We are doing a pilot study on microplastics using a fluorescence method (red nile). The dye is solvachromic, so it's emission spectrum changes by the polarity of the media. We do have the spectra for the excitation (mostly blue light) and emission (for the solvent used).

We have an old zeiss microscope equiped with epifluorescence. The filter has emission in 460-490, FT510 and LP at 520.

1. My question is if the emission spectrum of red nile includes 510-520 but maxima is achievied at 560, the filter set we have will work and we will see green fluorescence?
2. In others types of microplastics the spectrum of emission is shifted towards the red but it includes a small extitation in green. Is this filter useful?
   Hope someone can help we have applied the protocols but we doubt if there is a problem in the red nile solution or in the fluorescence filter

Comment: The  nile red fluorescence ranges from approx 530 to 700nm depend on solvent polarity so a fixed filter will be of v limited use. You really need to see the spectrum so it would be best to try and get a ccd attached to the microscope. There are many now that have fibre couplings and are relative cheap, I've used ones from Ocean Optics in the past. They probably have couplers to fit microscopes.

Comment: Thanks for responding,  we do have a camera in a modern microscope, but we do not have the fluorescence accesory. The FT and LT in the filter set will block the emitted fluorescence? We try using blue leds and arduino as suggested in some papers but we see red fluorescence or yellow and it is supposed to fluorescence in green. How can we easily test if the red nile solution is working fine?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by the filter has emission in 460-490, and what exactly are the FT510 and LP520 filters i assume that hey transmit at these wavelengths. Are they narrow band or edge interference filters or something else?

Comment: You first need to look at the transmission characteristics of each filter before choosing any filter.

Comment: Hi. I read more and more and as far as I understand, the filter set we have emits blue light (460-490), has dichroic beamspitter FT510 and a longpass filter of 520. So as much as I understand any emission above 520 will be visible. In fact we see red and yellow fibers after red nile dying. I suspect that the dye may not be working well since the stock solution was prepared long ago in DSMO and were kept at dark but not refrigerated. We are new at this, have followed the protocols but we cannot clearly see the classic green fluorescence of most microplastic.

Comment: @AnastD, You are using the wrong word for filters. A filter does not emit. It transmits a given range of light.

Comment: As @M.Farooq says, your filters are characterized by their transmittances versus wavelength. It seems like you want to illuminate your plastic specimens with blue light, then the dichroic beamsplitter does something unclear to me and then you want to use the 560 nm long pass filter to observe the green fluorescence. Is this anywhere near accurate? It would help us if you edited to include a simple diagram. By the way, it is Nile red, not red nile.

Comment: From the wikipedia article on [Nile red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nile_red), you will get different emission spectra depending on the solvent. So look at the spectra there, see what it shows for DMSO (if it does) and what solvents give green emission spectra, and then try exciting with a cheap UV flashlight or your blue LED.

Comment: I also think you should sketch what you have as setup or in mind. I imagine that you have white light or so light, and want to narrow it in a way to observe fluorescence with higher contrast. But it is not clear..

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and apologize for some incorrect expressions due to my English language. We now have the spectra of different types of plastics dyed with Nile Red with different solvents to explore. I did not clearly understood the LP specifications of the old epifluorescence microscope and the question was not properly formulated. We will try with a UV or a blue led lamp. Thanks for your time reading this!